# Directory of MOLS that are prime powers?

Tags: reference-request, latin-square

I had stumbled across a page earlier today that contained the maximally sized sets for mutually orthogonal latin squares of prime power order. I cannot, however, find this page again. Would you be able to help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set of (n-1)-MOLS(n), for prime power n, can be constructed similar to the constructed for prime n I mentioned in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169763) other question, by generalising to finite fields.  A proof is available in e.g.:

> P. J. Cameron, Combinatorics: Topics, Techniques, Algorithms, (1994), Cambridge University Press.