# Prove that a certain type of Latin squares does not have any transversals

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

A **transversal** in an $n$ by $n$ Latin square is a set of $n$ element, each from a different row and a different column, in which every symbol (value) appears exactly once.

Prove that for **even** $n$, the Latin square below does not have any transversal:
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&\dots&n-1&n\\2&3&\dots&n&1\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\n&1&\dots&n-2&n-1\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Hint: What is the sum mod $n$?

Comment: @SeanEberhard Since $n$ is even, it's $n/2$ right?
However I fail to see the solution. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Well, the $(i, j)$ entry is $i+j-1$ mod $n$. Try computing the sum of the entries in a transversal in a different way.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Thank you very much!